# insert database using pdo with datetime and auto increment

Tags: pdo

I have tried to insert into a database with an auto increment number and date, but it's not working. 
This is my table from the database:

```
id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
dates datetime
```

This is my code

```
$dates=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$stmt=$conn->prepare('insert into tblpdo values(:id,:dates)');
$stmt->execute(array(':id',':dates'=>$dates));
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not
>   defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found myself. must declare column and not input id with auto increment

$stmt=$conn->prepare('insert into tblpdo(dates) values(:dates)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':dates'=>$dates));

Answer (score 0):

In prepate statement you put `:id` parameter but not include in `execute` function .there is no need to insert `id`  because it is auto increment but if you want to add than define it

`$id = 5 ;
 $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id,':dates'=>$dates));`

or if you want to follow auto increment

`$stmt=$conn->prepare('insert into tblpdo values(:dates)');
 $stmt->execute(array(':dates'=>$dates));`

Comment: still not work, i try use second method
Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1